Installation of Tutor edx palm version on AWS EKS with custom openedx
I installed tutor edx Palm version on AWS EKS with load balancer. But not able to deploy custom openedx or my_repo to EKS.
I configured in deployment.yml also but the code is not deployed.

Changed DOCKER_REPO with my repo and applied.
run the command "kubectl edit deployment lms -n openedx"

changed the docker image repo to my_image.
after that also not working.



